# Auto play images and video in series one after another

Tags: android, timer, handler

i am new in android and i have a task to make a application that play first some image (5 image)in full screen one by one every 20 sec after showing 5 images a video play for a given time and then image play again same manner.
means first play

image 1

after 20 sec

image 2

after 20 sec

image 3

after 20 sec

image 4

after 20 sec

image 5

Then play video in series..

video play 2 min (or given time)

then again image play same manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Timer().schedule to implement auto play

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            autoplay(index);
        }
}, 0,20000); 

void autoplay(int index){
    //imageview or videoview
}
```